# How to view the changelog for a package in a PPA?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, changelog

I understand that as `apt-get changelog <package>` gets its changelogs from `changelog.ubuntu.com`, running this command does not work to get the changelog for a package in a PPA, and the only real way that I have found is to `apt-get source <package>` and then look in `debian/changelog`. Is there a more efficient way of viewing the changelog of a package that is in a PPA in Terminal?

Comment: You can see changelog in a browser at ppa homepage.

Comment: @Pilot6: Yes, but I want to do it in Terminal in an efficient way.

Comment: I added another script that checks the package version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last changes to a PPA package can bee seen at

```
https://launchpad.net/~<ppa_user_name>/+archive/ubuntu/<PPA_name>/+files/<package_name>_<package_version>_source.changes
```

You can write a simple script that will extract this data.

The script can be like this

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -q -O - https://launchpad.net/~$1/+archive/ubuntu/$2/+files/$3_$4_source.changes | \
awk '/Changes:/{f=1;next}/Checksums/{f=0}flag'
```

Run it this way:

```
./changelog.sh <ppa_user_name> <ppa_name> <package_name> <package_version>
```

e.g.

```
./changelog.sh hanipouspilot rtlwifi rtlwifi-new-dkms 0.5
```

If you need a full changelog, not only the last entry, then you have to download and extract source. That can be also done by a script.

**Another script that checks changelog of an installed pacakage**

```
#!/bin/bash

data=`apt-cache policy $1 | awk '/\*\*\*/ {print $2} f{print $2;f=0} /\*\*\*/{f=1}'`
version=`echo $data | awk '{print $1}'`
version=`echo $version | sed -r s/^[0-9]+://`
URL=`echo $data | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ -z `echo $URL | grep ppa` ]; then
    echo "The package is not installed from PPA"
    exit
else
    user=`echo $URL | cut -d / -f 4`
    name=`echo $URL | cut -d / -f 5`
    wget  -q -O - https://launchpad.net/~$user/+archive/ubuntu/$name/+files/$1_${version}_source.changes | \
    awk '/Changes:/{f=1;next}/Checksums/{f=0}f' 
fi
```

It can be run by

```
./changelog.sh <package_name>
```

Comment: Is there no way then to specifically just download part of the source (the bit that contains the changelog) and then just extract that? Or does it not work like that?

Comment: You can't download a part of an archive. But you can download a full archive, then extract a file from it.

Comment: What if the archive is very large though, is there no way of going around downloading the entire archive?

Comment: I do not think there is a way. Launchpad will not extract a file for you.

Comment: If I contacted Debian, is there any way they could do it differently so that something like `apt-get changelog <package>` would work?

Comment: Nobody will do it for PPA. Is I said before, changelogs from ppa are not stored in any place except source tarballs.

Comment: Maybe that needs to change though.

Comment: @A.B. I added another one.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: You can download the *.debian.tar.xz source file, and extract the debian/changelog file from it.

Comment: The `apt-get changelog` is a special feature where the remote distribution maintained host is queried with a custom protocol to fetch the changelog. It would be great if it also worked for PPAs and custom repositories (such as Google and Opera repositories).